# Call to undefined method newCollection when using factories with Laravel-Doctrine

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, laravel-factory, laravel-doctrine

I would like to use [Model factories](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/seeding), but I get this error:

```
1) Tests\Factory\UserFactoryTest::testUserCount
Error: Call to undefined method App\Entities\User::newCollection()

C:\Projects\factory_test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:228
C:\Projects\factory_test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:178
C:\Projects\factory_test\tests\Factory\UserFactoryTest.php:21
```

The factory code was copied from the [Laravel-Doctrine example project](https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/Laravel-Doctrine-Quickstart/blob/master/database/factories/ModelFactory.php) :

```
$factory->define(App\Entities\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->title,
    ];
});
```

What do I wrong? Do I need additional configurations, before using factories? Doctrine works perfectly, I only have issue with `factory()`

The test class looks like this:

```
class UserFactoryTest extends TestCase {

    private $users = array();

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->users = factory(User::class, 3)->create();
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: It would seem that `$factory` in your case is still using Eloquent. Reading [this article](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/current/orm/testing) explains that it should be an instance of `LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Testing\Factory` as long as the factory file is located in `database/factories`.

Comment: `$factory` is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory`. But I don't understand why, because my Facory class is located in `database/factories`

Comment: I would double check that you have gone through all of the setup steps located [here](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.4/orm/installation), specifically the steps involving the ServiceProvider and configuration publishing.

Comment: @leek I tried that, but I still get that error

Comment: try `$this->users = entity(User::class, 3)->create();` in your `setUp` function instead of `factory()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `setUp()` function is using the standard Laravel `factory()` helper to generate the test data.

Change this to:

```php
protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->users = entity(User::class, 3)->create();
    //             ^^^^^^
}
```

The Laravel Doctrine [`entity()` helper method](https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/orm/blob/03dd5eda68a2f138c7d51d5bad5a788b46a4f0fb/src/helpers.php#L13) uses a different base class behind the scenes than the standard Laravel `factory()` helper method.

```
// Laravel Doctrine
$factory = app('LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Testing\Factory');
```

Compare to the [`factory()` helper method](http://8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L495) in the Laravel framework:

```php
// Laravel framework
$factory = app(EloquentFactory::class);
```